# How do I test error/close handlers (trigger errors) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, websocket

I'm trying to test `onclose` and `onerror` event handlers on a `WebSocket` connection. How do I properly test these functions, stubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check onclose just by putting a console log in the function and turning off the websocket server. As for onError each browser handles it differently, i think firefox will trigger it on a disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Demo for receiving error messages

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta charset = "utf-8" />
   <title>WebSocket Test</title>

   <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
      var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
      var output;
  
      function init() {
         output = document.getElementById("output");
         testWebSocket();
      }
  
      function testWebSocket() {
         websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
   
         websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
            onOpen(evt)
         };
   
         websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
            onClose(evt)
         };
   
         websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
            onError(evt)
         };
      }
  
      function onOpen(evt) {
         writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
         doSend("WebSocket rocks");
      }
  
      function onClose(evt) {
         writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
      }
  
      function onError(evt) {
         writeToScreen('<span style = "color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
      } 
  
      function doSend(message) {
         writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); websocket.send(message);
      }
  
      function writeToScreen(message) {
         var pre = document.createElement("p"); 
         pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word"; 
         pre.innerHTML = message; output.appendChild(pre);
      }
  
      window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
   </script>
 
   <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
   <div id = "output"></div>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood my question, wanted to know the simplest way to trigger these close/error so ensure my handlers will work as intended.